# Filtering the item from the string (list) in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am trying to find the county from all the list in my dataframe.
My dataframe looks like:

```
address_df
```

output:

```
   address

1   (4070, Halleck Street, Emeryville, Alameda Cou...

2   (Rancho Road, Yuba County, California, 95961, ...

3   (Jasper Lane, Yuba County, California, 95692, ...

4   (Yuba County, California, 95692, United States...
```

From this, I want to get all the element with the word "county"

For example, the output would be:

```
county

Alameda County

Yuba County

Yuba County

Yuba County
```

I first tried converting the string to the list but then I realized that the index of each is different that I cannot just simply take out the county using indexes.

Help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that converts the dataframe to a list, extracts the counties and creates a new dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'address':["(4070, Halleck Street, Emeryville, Alameda County)","(Rancho Road, Yuba County, California, 95961)",
 "(Jasper Lane, Yuba County, California, 95692)", "(Yuba County, California, 95692, United States)"]})

lst = df.to_numpy().tolist()
counties = []
for address in lst:
    address_parts = address[0].split(",")
    for part in address_parts:
        if 'County' in part:
            c = part.replace('(','').replace(')','').lstrip(' ').split(' ')
            counties.append(c[0])
counties_df = pd.DataFrame(counties, columns= ['counties'])

print(counties_df)

#output:
  counties
0  Alameda
1     Yuba
2     Yuba
3     Yuba
```

Comment: How would I filter the results that does not have a county in the address?

Comment: If the county does not always occur in the same location in the address or if its is not followed by the word "County", there is no way to access it unless you have a list of all county names to which you could compare each address.

Comment: I am not sure why but I had 1890 rows but after, I got 1904 rows..

Comment: Sorry I am new to this page! I will make sure to learn. Then, Is there any way to choose the first county from the list?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this is what you want:

```
address_df[address_df["address"].str.contains("county", case = False)]
```

Comment: I tried it but it is giving me an error: KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,\n              ...\n              nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],\n             dtype='float64', length=1890)] are in the [columns]"

Comment: What does `address_df.dtype` give you?

Comment: The output is dtype('O').